# why am i getting a syntax error on this token?

Tags: sql, jdbc

Working in JDBC and I keep getting a syntax token error for the `hoursWorkedToday` token, even though it is a legitimate variable, and `hoursWorked` is a  column name.  Types match up as well.

```
projectUpdate.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO projectLog (hoursWorked, weyerhaeuserWork, sudokuWork,websiteWork, scriptWork," +
                    "tropeWork) VALUES ("hoursWorkedToday +",'"+internWork+"','"+sudokuWork+"', '"+websiteWork+"' ,'"+scriptWork+"' ,'"+tropeWork+"')");
```

Getting the error on the `hoursWorkedToday` again, not sure why....the syntax matches up with other queries I have run, for example...

```
workoutUpdate.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO workoutLog (workedOut, milesRan, comments) VALUES (1,"+miles+" ,"+
                    workoutComments+"')");
```

Answer (score 2):

`VALUES ("hoursWorkedToday` is not syntactically correct. You're missing a `+` symbol.

I would strongly recommend that you use `PreparedStatement`s rather than assembling the SQL string yourself. PreparedStatements are faster (the DB driver will compile and re-use them), easier to use, and protect you from SQL injection.

You could replace your query with a PreparedStatement like so:

```
PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO projectLog(hoursWorked, weyerhaeuserWork, sudokuWork,websiteWork, scriptWork, tropeWork) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
p.setInt(1, hoursWorkedToday);
...
p.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

> projectUpdate.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO projectLog (hoursWorked,
>   weyerhaeuserWork, sudokuWork,websiteWork, scriptWork," + "tropeWork) 
>   VALUES ('"+hoursWorkedToday+"','"+internWork+"','"+sudokuWork+"', '"+websiteWork+"' ,'"+scriptWork+"' ,'"+tropeWork+"')");

Not sure but it works , but you may try . you didn't add '' to hoursWorkedToday+

Answer (score 0):

You missed a plus sign between the end quote and hoursWorkedToday:

```
projectUpdate.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO projectLog (hoursWorked, weyerhaeuserWork, sudokuWork,websiteWork, scriptWork," +
"tropeWork) VALUES (" + hoursWorkedToday +",'"+internWork+"','"+sudokuWork+"', '"+websiteWork+"' ,'"+scriptWork+"' ,'"+tropeWork+"')");
--                    ^ here
```